# How to show details by default with NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

With NSIS a basic build will have a "Show Details" button which will show the installer script messages.  Is there a way to make this the default such that the user does not have to click "Show Details"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set [ShowInstDetails](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.34) attribute to `show`

Comment: SetDetailsView show  ; as documented on that linked page, this is a way to toggle it from inside a section

Comment: how to set ShowInstDetails to transparent ?.